# Vue inline template not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

When using [Vue inline template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates), I was expecting the following code to render a,b,c in a table. Instead, it renders nothing with no console errors. What am I doing wrong?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(function() {

    app = new Vue({

      el: '#app',

      data: {
        items: ["a", "b", "c"]
      }
    });

    Vue.component('items-component', {

      props: ['items'],

      computed: {

        showTable: function() {
          return this.items.length > 0
        }
      }
    })
  })
</script>

<div id="app">
  <items-component inline-template>
    <table v-if="showTable">
      <tr v-for="item in items">
        <td>{{item}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need jQuery wrapper to run your Vue code.

Second, you should specify data in your component, not on constructor.

Third, You are expecting a prop on your `items-component` to get, but not sending any, you should remove it too. Also data must return an object, and it should be a function

Below, the working one

https://jsfiddle.net/2yyjy3bc/1/

Comment: I actually need to fetch the data (ajax) from inside of the app Vue instance and pass it into multiple child components. That's why I tried to use props. How can I pass props? I tried "<items-component :items="items" inline-template>" but that doesn't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/2yyjy3bc/2/ here is an example of it. But I don't recommend you to do it like this. In my opinion you have to manage your data inside items-component itself. Or you can use [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/) store to manage application data @Sergey